# Find out the system frequency in wince 7

Tags: c++, windows-ce, cpu-speed

I have a system that runs on wince 7.

I have encountered a problem in which the system slows down after a while.

How can I find out the system frequency?

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods (depending on the information you want):

You can use the toolhelp api to find how much processor time each application is using. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159461/Mobile-Processor-Usage

IOCTL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION will tell you what kind of processor is in your system and what clock speed it is running at. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/122843/What-processor-is-in-my-mobile-device

GetIdleTime() can be used to tell you how busy your processor is overall: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/133104/Mobile-processor-usage

Comment: `IOCTL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION` works like a charm in PB. Thanks.